# regex to match subexpression at end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test whether the ending pattern in a string is an html closing tag (assuming trailing spaces are trimmed).

```
var str1 = "<em>I</em> am <strong>dummy</strong> <em>text.</em>"; //ends with html close tag
var str2 = "<em>I</em> am <strong>dummy</strong> <strong>text.</strong>"; //ends with html close tag
var str3 = "<em>I</em> am <strong>dummy</strong> text"; //does not end with html close tag
```

Using str1 above, I would like to get the position of the ending tag, which is an . Here are my attempts:

```
var rgx1 = /(<\/em>)$/g; // works. basic scenario. matches closing </em> tags at the end of the string.
var rgx2 = /<\s*\/\s*\w\s*.*?>/g; //matches html closing tags.
var rgx3 = /<\s*\/\s*\w\s*.*?>$/g; //doesn't work. supposed to match closing html tag at the end of the string

console.log(str.search(rgx1))
```

While rgx1 correctly returns the position of the ending  tag, and rgx2 correctly returns the position of a closing html tag in general, I'm trying get a generalized regex that will return the positing of any html tag that ends the string. Why doesn't rgx3 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just use a negative char class to match anything that's not a closing >

`var rgx = /<\/[^>]+>$/g;`

as to why rgx3 didn't work... your pattern isn't really good but it should technically match... if it didn't work with the $ on the end there, then the string you are matching probably isn't trimmed as you suppose it to be (or some other thing on the end other than closing html tag)

Comment: if I use a negative char class it may match non valid html tags, such as **</<div>** with the extra < tag. There is nothing else at the end of the string, so I'm confused why the end $ isn't doing it's job.

Comment: well my answer to that is..why are you trying to accommodate invalid html tags?  You should be fixing the issue of having invalid html tags, rather than trying to bandaid with a regex.  By that logic, you should be using alternation to only match strictly valid html tags, because </alksfdjsdlkfj> is invalid, and yet your regex will match it just the same.  And I don't know what else to tell you... if no `$` works, but yes `$` doesn't... that there has to be something else after that last `>`

Comment: Thanks fair point about the alternation. `/<\/[^>]+>$/g` does work so I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there might be an issue with rgx2 and rgx3 - an extra .*? before the > and a missing * after \w - here's how I would write the regexes. The fact that rgx2 was working at all was because of the match all (.*)

```
var rgx2 = /<\s*\/\s*\w*\s*>/g;
var rgx3 = /<\s*\/\s*\w*\s*>$/g;
```

Comment: The regex would still technically match `<\s*\/\s*\w\s*.*?>` would match literal `<` followed by 0 or more whitespace chars, followed by literal `/` followed by 0 or more whitespace chars, followed by 1 'word' char, followed by 0 or more whitespace chars, followed by 0 or more of anything, followed by literal `>` This technically would match any closing tag, though it's terribly inefficient.  And you can see from rgx2 vs. rgx3, the difference is the $ anchor, so the problem is what comes after his tag regex